# PLSQL record or collection into json object

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to convert a Pl/SQl record or collection into json object using json_object(*) function.Is it possible or is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

As long as they are database types (not solely PLSQL types) you could do it with a table function, eg

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  type the_row as object (
  3    x int,
  4    y int );
  5  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  type the_row_list as table
  3  of the_row
  4  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> -- interestingly, direct SELECT fails
SQL>
SQL> select json_object(*)
  2  from table(the_row_list(the_row(1,1),the_row(2,2)));
select json_object(*)
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-40579: star expansion is not allowed


SQL> -- but a WITH is ok
SQL> with t as
  2  (
  3  select *
  4  from table(the_row_list(the_row(1,1),the_row(2,2)))
  5  )
  6  select json_object(*)
  7  from t;

JSON_OBJECT(*)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
{"X":1,"Y":1}
{"X":2,"Y":2}
```